# Use of global var in multithreaded camera frame ready events

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing an application that depends on fast image manipulation. It might sound strange but I'm doing this C# and not in C++. So far this has not been a limitation, I can process an image realtime. While I do quite some complex things with the image and I do this under 30ms.

I changed the program to make sure that the image stream would never queue
by simply checking a boolean to check if a current frame is not being processed. Normally this wouldn't happen, but in some cases it did. For example when run the app in VS2010 debug mode, or when the PC is doing also other heavy tasks, and has less CPU resources.

In such case I would like to skip new frame processing, so processing them won't queue. In such cases it would be better to just work with last known data which is still being processed, and thus waiting would be the fastest method then to retrieve an answer.

So I started with something like:

```
private void Camera_FrameReady(object Sender, ImageEvent e)
{
  if (!IsImageReady) return;  // global var
  IsImageReady = false;
  //... do stuff with the image
  IsImageReady=true;
}
```

This didn't workout, as I had hoped. And I think it has to do with the threading nature of events within the C# compiler. So then I tried to resolve it by de-registering and re-registering the `Camera_FrameReady` ready, but the camera takes to much time to restart, so that didn't workout.

Strangely now it seams to work with the code below but I'm not sure why it does.

```
private void Camera_FrameReady(object Sender, ImageEvent e)
{
   Update_Image(e)
}

private void Update_Image(e)
{
  if (!IsImageReady) return;  // global var
  IsImageReady = false;
  //... do stuff with the image
  IsImageReady=true;
}
```

This makes me wonder about how C# gets compiled. Does it work like that whenever `Camera_FrameReady` is called it has a "world view" of the current global values? Or that global variables are only updated after the processing of an event?

Comment: do you mean re-registering the Camera_FrameReady _method_ or _event_?

Comment: A *bool* is not a proper synchronization object.  You need Monitor.TryEnter() with a timeout of 0.

Comment: @Hans the firing of the camera events isnt done with my code, so i dont have that kind of control over it. (ea i am not writing a driver for the camera), the event is simply just raised at 1/33 of a second.

@ Tim, CameraReady += new EventHandler ...

Comment: That has nothing to do with it.  *Replace* your bool with a Monitor.

Comment: Why do you think the Camera object fires the events multithreaded? Is it possible that a `Camera_FrameReady' fires twice?

Comment: @jeroen Good thinking!, the firing of threads might indeed not be multi-threaded, however as single threaded, it can still be launched (as event) faster then it can be processed, when the PC is under heavy load, and so threads would buildup then..  
hmm a deep one I need to think about your comment a bit more as it still leaves me wondering then why my first solution didn't work

Comment: @user613326 my example  shows how to process those images on a differnt thread and prevent image queueing.

Comment: thanks, but i mainly wonder why my last example does work.

Comment: thanks, but i mainly wonder why my last example did work, i dont understand that, must be something related about how functions are called in .net perhaps ?. I have now added some other logic that skips camera event processing, by a global boolean, to jump out those new frame event routines, if processing is bussy. Maybe a bit dirty coding but this way it works now even faster i achieved around 10ms reduction. And a bit constanter processing time (however my programming PC runs to many apps to decently test my app, main cause of queueing )

Answer (score 1):

The first thing came in my head is that  the `Camera_FrameReady` event blocks the acquisition thread. But that doesn't explain why the second solution works..

---

So if you want to process the images parallel to the acquisition thread, you should create a new thread for processing.

---

For example: When there is a new image, check if the processing thread is busy. If the processing thread is busy, you shouldn't wait or queue (like you wanted) but just skip this image. If the processing thread is waiting for work, store the image in a 'global' variable, so the processing thread can access it and signal the processing thread.

I made an example for you: (pseudo)

```
    // the thread for the processing.
    private Thread _processingThread;

    // a signal to check if the workerthread is busy with an image
    private ManualResetEvent _workerThreadIsBusy = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // request for terminating
    private ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // confirm terminated
    private ManualResetEvent _terminated = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // store the current image.
    private Image _myImage;

    // event callback for new images
    private void Camera_FrameReady(object Sender, ImageEvent e)
    {
        // is the workerthread already processing an image? return.. (skip this image)
        if (_workerThreadIsBusy.WaitOne(0))
            return; // skip frame.

        //create a 'global' ref so the workerthread can access it.

        /* BE CAREFULL HERE. You might experience trouble with the instance of this image. 
         * You are creating another reference to the SAME instance of the image 
         * to process on another thread. When the Camera is reusing this 
         * image (for speed), the image might screwed-up. In that case, 
         * you have to create a copy!         
         * (personally I would reuse the image which makes the image not available outside the event callback) */

        _myImage = e.Image;

        // signal the workerthread, so it starts processing the current image.
        _workerThreadIsBusy.Set();
    }

    private void ImageProcessingThread()
    {
        var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[] { _terminating, _workerThreadIsBusy };
        var run = true;

        while (run)
        {
            switch (EventWaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles))
            {
                case 0:
                    // terminating.
                    run = false;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    // process _myImage

                    ProcessImage(_myImage);

                    _workerThreadIsBusy.Reset();
                    break;
            }
        }
        _terminated.Set();
    }

    private void ProcessImage(Image _myImage)
    {
        // whatever...
    }

    // constructor
    public MyCameraProcessor()
    {
        // define the thread.
        _processingThread = new Thread(ImageProcessingThread);
        _processingThread.Start();

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _terminating.Set();
        _terminated.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: if (_workerThreadIsBusy.WaitOne(0))...
wouldnt that detect itself as well as a threat ?...

Comment: `_workerThreadIsBusy` is a `ManualResetEvent` and is set when there is an image. So when the thread is busy with the `_myImage` the `_workerThreadIsBusy` is `Set`. So `_workerThreadIsBusy.WaitOne(0)` will return true is the workerthread is still busy processing. When the workerthread is ready, it will `Reset` the `_workerThreadIsBusy`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not multithreading safe

```
  if (!IsImageReady) return;  // global var
  IsImageReady = false;
  //... do stuff with the image
  IsImageReady=true;
```

2 threads can read IsImageReady at the same time, see that it is true and both set it then to false. You might also get problems if the processor is reading IsImageReady from cache and not from memory. You can avoid these kind of problems with the Interlocked class, which reads and changes the value in one operation. It also ensures that the cache doesn't cause problems.

```
private int IsImageReady= 0; 

private void Camera_FrameReady(object Sender, ImageEvent e){
  int wasImageReady = Interlocked.Exchange(ref IsImageReady, 1);
  if (wasImageReady ==1) return;

    //do something
    IsImageReady= 0;
  }
}
```

Although I am not sure if that is your only problem. You might have also others. To be sure, you have to debug your code properly, which is very difficult when it involves multithreading. Read my article [Codeproject: Debugging multithreaded code in real time](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/792532/Debugging-multithreaded-code-in-real-time) how you can do it.

Comment: Its unlikely this will happen, the reason is it's not that 2 threads get fired to read camera data, its the opposite behavior the camera will create a thread on arrival of a new image. The philosophy here is that its better to drop a frame then to create a queue. A video camera has about 20ms (30fps) delay per trigger. In theory it still be it highly unlikely could happen, the other part of dealing width camera's is to keep execution time below 20ms, this dequeues faster then triggers can be made.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking that you could have also other problems. But when you do multithreading programming, you have to carefully avoid concurrency issues like reading/writing a flag in 2 operations. By the way: Windows is not a real time operation system guaranteeing a certain response time and it could happen that Windows causes a delay of 20ms and the error occurs.

Comment: I think your first comment though says it all, its indeed not multithreading safe. Its true as essentially a new frame event is not a parallel triggered event. The event feed of new frames is a single thread. Sure it can happen fast (if a camera could have an internal queue ) but most camera's dont work like that, they just stream (overwrite) a single data buffer.